# How can I create task in asana from setting asana to forward emails back

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I'm using Asana for forwarding email from other website that I post email for any comments, but the method was is any one can send email to *elp@***.net and as I set asana to forward this email to asana to create new task

Comment: I am afraid that your question is a bit labyrinthine. I suggest that you edit the question and describe step-by-step what you currently have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am currently using the Asana Project Management‎ for a class. The assignment i have to complete is to set up an email for students to be able to express complaints about any technical issues of the school website. When someone sends an email explaining the complaints they are supposed to automatically be forwarded to Asana Project Management‎, but Asana doesn't create tasks for any of the students that are not signed up with the program Asana. How to i make it where anybody even not associated with Asana can send their complaints to my email with Asana?

Answer (score 0):

You can only e-mail in tasks to projects that you have access to. So either, every student needs to get access to the project, or you create a centralized e-mail account that students will e-mail, and that e-mail account will e-mail in a task to the appropriate project.

With regards to allowing only students sending e-mails from a valid school e-mail address to create tasks, I believe this can be accomplished by setting the appropriate e-mail forwarding rules.

And in case you haven't seen it yet, you can check out the [Asana guide](https://asana.com/guide/help/email/email-to-asana).

Comment: I am currently using the Asana Project Management‎ for a class. The assignment i have to complete is to set up an email for students to be able to express complaints about any technical issues of the school website. When someone sends an email explaining the complaints they are supposed to automatically be forwarded to Asana Project Management‎, but Asana doesn't create tasks for any of the students that are not signed up with the program Asana. How to i make it where anybody even not associated with Asana can send their complaints to my email with Asana?

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to provide students with an e-mail address such that if they e-mail that e-mail address, an Asana task gets created.

Comment: What e-mail are you currently having them send e-mails to?

Comment: One thing you could do is set up some e-mail account, say support@school.com, which is associated with your Asana account (or has its own account). Then, whenever this account receives an e-mail from a student, it forwards an appropriate formed e-mail to Asana to create a task (in either its My Tasks or a specific project) according to the instructions in the Asana guide [link](https://asana.com/guide/help/email/email-to-asana)

Answer (score 0):

I have made email for the school and is belong to the school, but we only wants the student with@dewv.edu can send email to Asana, I found out only the members when they send emails, it create under task, but when other student send I only receive the email.